# Can any one give me some idea how to write a test class for the below mentioned code

Tags: apex, unit-test, developer

Can any one give me some idea how to write a test class for the below mentioned code struggling for this.

```
public with sharing class Select_Distributor_Controller {

    public string partnerId{get;set;}
    public List<PartnerAccWrapper> PartnerAccs {get;set;}
    public String SelectedDisti{get;set;}
    public String selectedid{get;set;}
    public Map<String,Disti_Account_Relationship__c> partnerdetails=new Map<String,Disti_Account_Relationship__c>();
    public Map<String,String> acctids=new Map<String,String>();
    public List<String> names=new List<String>();
    public pageReference resPage{get;set;}
    public String checkSignlerecord{get;set;}

    public Select_Distributor_Controller (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
    public void getResults(){
        PartnerAccs=null;
        checkSignlerecord='';
        partnerId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('partnerId');
        SelectedDisti =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('acc'); 
        names.add(SelectedDisti);
        system.debug('selected id--'+  SelectedDisti ); 
        for(Account a : [select id,name from account where type='Distributor' and  Name =:SelectedDisti]){
            acctids.put(a.name,a.id);
        }
        if(partnerId!=null){
            PartnerAccs=new List<PartnerAccWrapper>();
            for(Disti_Account_Relationship__c dst:[select id, name, Partner_Account__r.name,Distributor__r.Name,Select_Reseller_Disti_ID__c,Disti_Latte_Id__c  from Disti_Account_Relationship__c where Distributor__c=:acctids.get(SelectedDisti) and 
                                                   Partner_Account__c=:partnerId order by createddate]){
                                                       partnerdetails.put(dst.name,dst);
                                                       PartnerAccs.add(new PartnerAccWrapper(dst));         

                                                   }
            if(PartnerAccs.size()==1){
                checkSignlerecord='checked';
                selectedid=PartnerAccs[0].disti.name;

            }        
        }

    }

    public PageReference UpdateSPR(){

        if(selectedid!=''){
            List<SPR__c> sprs=[select id,name,Account__c,Reseller_DistiID_SPR__c from SPR__c where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];    

            if(partnerdetails.get(selectedid)!=null){
                sprs[0].account__c= partnerdetails.get(selectedid).Distributor__c;
                sprs[0].Reseller_DistiID_SPR__c= partnerdetails.get(selectedid).Name;                    
            }
            update sprs[0]; 
            resPage=new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
            resPage.setRedirect(true);
        }else{
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Please select the record.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            resPage=null;
        }
        return resPage;      
    }

    public PageReference cancel() {
        return new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
    } 

    public class PartnerAccWrapper{

        public Disti_Account_Relationship__c disti{get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public PartnerAccWrapper(Disti_Account_Relationship__c a) {
            disti = a;
            selected = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I rolled back the edit as the code seems to have been removed....For context of the question I thought it might be best to leave the code?

Answer (score 1):

I found this article very helpful. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

> This article provides an introduction to starting your test method
>   development. It explores the syntax for creating test methods, shows
>   how to execute these tests, and provide best practice advice. Test
>   methods are not intended to be roadblocks to your development. Rather,
>   they ensure your success. Do not approach testing and developing your
>   test methods as an afterthought. Test methods should be written during
>   the development effort. Valid test methods will provide you with an
>   automated test suite to ensure quality and execute regression testing.

It will provide you all details regarding how the test class would be written. Its best practices and simple example to show you how test class looks like.

Go through every line of that URL and you would learn the way to write test class.

You simply need to create scenario in test methods in test class which you are doing in main code.

Comment: But i am unable to get coverage for this class.any help

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest
 Public class Select_Distributor_controller_Test{

        static testMethod void myTestUnit(){


          Account acc = new Account();

          acc.Name = 'Test Account';
         insert acc;  

         ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', acc.id);
         ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('acc'); 


        Contact con = new Contact();

       con.FirstName = 'Test First Name';
     con.LastName = 'Test Last Name';
      con.AccountId = acc.Id;

       insert con;



               Test.StartTest();

            PageReference pageRef = Page.Select_Distributor_VF; 

            pageRef.getParameters().put('partnerId', String.valueOf(acc.Id));

            pageRef.getParameters().put('acc', String.valueOf(acc.Id));




            Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(acc);

            Select_Distributor_Controller testSelect_Distributor_VF = new Select_Distributor_Controller(sc);

            testSelect_Distributor_VF .getResults();

            testSelect_Distributor_VF .UpdateSPR();


    Test.StopTest();


 }
}
```

Class

```
public with sharing class Select_Distributor_Controller {

public string partnerId{get;set;}
public List<PartnerAccWrapper> PartnerAccs {get;set;}
public String SelectedDisti{get;set;}
public String selectedid{get;set;}
public Map<String,Disti_Account_Relationship__c> partnerdetails=new Map<String,Disti_Account_Relationship__c>();
public Map<String,String> acctids=new Map<String,String>();
public List<String> names=new List<String>();
public pageReference resPage{get;set;}
public String checkSignlerecord{get;set;}

  public Select_Distributor_Controller (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
public void getResults(){
        PartnerAccs=null;
        checkSignlerecord='';
        partnerId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('partnerId');
        SelectedDisti =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('acc'); 
        names.add(SelectedDisti);
        system.debug('selected id--'+  SelectedDisti ); 
        for(Account a : [select id,name from account where type='Distributor' and  Name =:SelectedDisti]){
        acctids.put(a.name,a.id);
        }
               if(partnerId!=null){
               PartnerAccs=new List<PartnerAccWrapper>();
                for(Disti_Account_Relationship__c dst:[select id, name, Partner_Account__r.name,Distributor__r.Name,Select_Reseller_Disti_ID__c,Disti_Latte_Id__c  from Disti_Account_Relationship__c where Distributor__c=:acctids.get(SelectedDisti) and 
                                    Partner_Account__c=:partnerId order by createddate]){
                                   partnerdetails.put(dst.name,dst);
                                   PartnerAccs.add(new PartnerAccWrapper(dst));         

                                    }
                           if(PartnerAccs.size()==1){
                           checkSignlerecord='checked';
                          selectedid=PartnerAccs[0].disti.name;

                           }        
                        }

}

public PageReference UpdateSPR(){

  if(selectedid!=''){
         List<SPR__c> sprs=[select id,name,Account__c,Reseller_DistiID_SPR__c from SPR__c where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];    

                            if(partnerdetails.get(selectedid)!=null){
                    sprs[0].account__c= partnerdetails.get(selectedid).Distributor__c;
                    sprs[0].Reseller_DistiID_SPR__c= partnerdetails.get(selectedid).Name;                    
                            }
              update sprs[0]; 
        resPage=new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
        resPage.setRedirect(true);
         }else{
          ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Please select the record.');
          ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
          resPage=null;
         }
return resPage;      
}

public PageReference cancel() {
        return new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
    } 

public class PartnerAccWrapper{

         public Disti_Account_Relationship__c disti{get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public PartnerAccWrapper(Disti_Account_Relationship__c a) {
            disti = a;
            selected = false;
        }

  }
}
```

Lines which were not covering

```
public pageReference resPage{get;set;}
        acctids.put(a.name,a.id);
        }
                                           partnerdetails.put(dst.name,dst);
                                   PartnerAccs.add(new PartnerAccWrapper(dst));         
                                                            checkSignlerecord='checked';
                          selectedid=PartnerAccs[0].disti.name;
                    sprs[0].account__c= partnerdetails.get(selectedid).Distributor__c;
                    sprs[0].Reseller_DistiID_SPR__c= partnerdetails.get(selectedid).Name;                    
                            }
              update sprs[0]; 
        resPage=new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
        resPage.setRedirect(true);
         }else{
          ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Please select the record.');
          ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
          resPage=null;
         }
return resPage;      

public PageReference cancel() {
        return new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
    } 
             public Disti_Account_Relationship__c disti{get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public PartnerAccWrapper(Disti_Account_Relationship__c a) {
            disti = a;
            selected = false;
        }
```

Comment: Hi nihar thanks for the reply have written something like this but its not covering anything

Comment: have you checked that which part of your class not covered ? (from developer console)

Comment: ya nihar but i didnot see any coverd line in developer console

Comment: OK. No problem. You can edit your question and show me class again.

Comment: nihar posted the test class and the class and the lines which were not covering